# How to set an EventHandler equal to another EventHandler

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, eventhandler

I am trying to create an extension method Clone() for a RichTextBox (RTB).

I want to set the TextChanged event handler of the new RTB to the TextChanged event handler of the old RTB. For example:

```
newRTB.TextChanged += oldRTB.TextChanged;
```

However, the following error is given:

"The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.TextChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=."

One possible solution is to add the event handler as a parameter to the clone method and just recreate the event, but I need to do this for multiple events and that would get cumbersome. Any ideas?

The "=" sign also does not seem to work.

Comment: You have code somewhere that initialized oldRTB.  Move that code into a separate method that takes a RichTextBox as an argument.  Now you can call it again, passing newRTB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could copy the events via `reflection`. Now i myself would be wary of doing this, so please test exhaustively and with all versions (2.0, 3.0, 4.0). I tried many ways but the following was the only way, i got it to work. A Smoke test was run on .NET 4.0.

**Create an extension method on the Form Class**

```
public static class FormExtension
{
   public static void CopyEvent(this Form form, Control src, string fieldName, string eventName, Control dest)
   {
       EventHandlerList events = (EventHandlerList)typeof(Control)
                                  .GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                  .GetValue(src, null);
       object key = typeof(Control).GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
       EventInfo evInfo = typeof(Control).GetEvent(eventName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
       Delegate del = events[key];
       if (del != null)
       {
           Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(evInfo.EventHandlerType, form, del.Method);
           MethodInfo addHandler = evInfo.GetAddMethod();
           Object[] addHandlerArgs = { d };
           addHandler.Invoke(dest, addHandlerArgs);
       }
   }
}
```

**Now use it like this**

Here i show an example of copying the `click` and the `text changed` event.

```
this.CopyEvent(richTextBox1, "EventText", "TextChanged", richTextBox2);
this.CopyEvent(richTextBox1, "EventClick", "Click", richTextBox2);
```

**How to use it for other events**

You would have to open the `Control` class via Reflector and get the `field` and the `eventnames`.

So in the case of `Text Changed` it was something like:

```
public event EventHandler TextChanged    <-----The Event name for the "CopyEvent" function
{
    add
    {
        base.Events.AddHandler(EventText, value);
    }
    remove
    {
        base.Events.RemoveHandler(EventText, value);
    }
}
```

where `EventText` is

```
private static readonly object EventText = new object();  <-------The Field name
```

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you. One question though, what do you mean by "other events"? Shouldn't the code above that be sufficient? I'm probably just missing something in the CopyEvent method.

Comment: By Other Events i mean, if you would like to copy other events like `DoubleClick`, `MouseUp` etc. apart from `TextChanged`, then you would have to look up their respective event names and properties in the `Control` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you precreate the TextChanged event, you can do this, in a form put two TextBox and a Button, this will make your controls share the event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textbox1_TextChanged);
}

private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("this");
}
```

**UPDATE**

in a different file, create the method you want, you can take the code of the current event and copy in this method, then you just assign it to the new controls

```
void MyCloned_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // Shared method OldRTB to share with NewRTB

}
```

In the form you will use it like this

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(MyCloned_TextChanged);
    textBox2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(MyCloned_TextChanged);
}
```

Comment: Same issue, this does not allow me to keep the code "clean" and inside of one method. I would still have to send Clone() the event "textbox1_TextChanged". I think it is likely I can't achieve exactly what I want...

Comment: Exactly you create the method and assign it to the controls that support TextChanged, outside the form to reuse everywhere in the application.

Comment: Remember, I need to use Clone, which is an extension method in its own seperate class. To do what you are saying, I would need to provide refernce to a different control, then inside of Clone(), "newRTB.TextChanged += someForm.some_TextChanged". Then I would have to do this for EVERY form that I want to steal a method from. This is possible if I throw some static events in, but still a step in the wrong direction. This also means I would have to hard code it, leaving no flexibility, since not every textbox will be using the same event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newRTB.TextChanged  += new TextChangedEventHandler(oldRTB_textChanged);
```

Create a method like this:

```
void oldRTB_textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this would only work if I send the Clone() method the parameter (oldRTB_textChanged), which I am trying to avoid.